# Limit number of mongodb documents inserted at the same time

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am using find to query and then insert almost 1000 documents in a mongodb collection.Is there a way to limit the number of documents being inserted at the same time.(My basic objective here is to find all documents with a particular year from a collection and then copy/insert them within the same collection with updated year and few other sections.The problem is when this API is in progress other API's gets a delay.So I need to change the concurrency rate at which these happens).

```
async function Options(fromYear,toYear){
await db.collection('Options').find({"year":parseInt(fromYear)}).forEach(function(doc){
    var newDoc = doc;
    delete newDoc._id;
    newDoc.year = parseInt(toYear);
    db.collection('Options').insert(newDoc);
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some code of what you have done until now?

Comment: have you tried to update instead of find and insert? looks like you dont need this but i am not sure

Comment: Collect all new documents and use insertMany for performance, also you can use projection {_id:0} and remove "delete newDoc._id", and if your server memory is enough use toArray instead of forEach, this will give you a lot of efficiency